# How do I have Android use a qualified resource file only on older devices?

Tags: android, right-to-left

I have a separate layout file for Arabic users, that I only want to use for devices that don't support Android's native RTL mirroring (introduced in API level 17). If they are using a device with API 17 or above, I want the default XML file to be used.

How would I accomplish this? I know:

If I put my `home.xml` in `res/layout/` then it is used as the default layout file.

If I put another `home.xml` in `res/layout-ar/` then it will be used for arabic speakers

If I put another `home.xml` in `res/layout-ar-v17/` then it will be used for arabic speakers with v17 or higher.*

*The problem is, I don't want to have another home.xml, I just want the system to use the default and mirror it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Layout Aliases](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).  You would end up with two layout files, let's call them home_one.xml and home_two.xml.  Then in `res/values/layout.xml` and the `res/values-ar-v17/layout.xml` you would have

```
<item name="home" type="layout">@layout/home_one</item>
```

and in `res/values-ar/layout.xml` you would need

```
<item name="home" type="layout">@layout/home_two</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating two reusable layouts (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)), one for the default layout and one for Arabic with API level 17+. Then you can define various `home.xml` files in appropriate configuration-specific folders so that they `<include>` (or `<merge>`) the appropriate layout. That way you only need to replication a single `<include>` tag instead of an entire layout.